# Running glmark2 with discrete graphics card: 60 fps cap

Tags: nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I wanted to verify that my NVIDIA discrete graphics card was functioning appropriately with bumblebee installed, in comparison to the intel integrated graphics card.

So, I ran `glmark2` and `optirun glmark2`, but for each new animation/test/whatever that glmark2 ran, the NVIDIA discrete graphics card (with optirun) would not produce higher than 60 fps (in fact, it produces 60 fps every single time). It also produced the following each time a new fps line was displayed:

```
** GLX does not support GLX_EXT_swap_control or GLX_MESA_swap_control!
** Failed to set swap interval. Results may be bounded above by refresh rate.
```

The Intel integrated card (no optirun - I realize this is redundant) generally produced fps figures of about 1200 on average, and produced no messages like those shown above.

It's not that big of a deal to get the numbers to go over 60 for the NVIDIA card, since the monitor can't do over 60fps anyways according to `xrandr`, but it'd just be interesting to know why those messages are produced and how that could be avoided, to see what sort of numbers the NVIDIA card can rack up compared to the Intel card.

But like I said it's not that big of a deal to get that figured out since bumblebee is clearly working quite nicely with the NVIDIA card, since the CPU barely even budges running through those tests with that card! That, and the quality produced for certain animations from the `glmark2` test is enormously better when it runs through the discrete NVIDIA card compared to the integrated Intel card.

Thanks for any input you may have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
vblank_mode=0 optirun glmark2
```

Apparently there's a cap in place to limit the FPS to the refresh rate of the monitor.

Comment: That worked and got it to bypass the FPS limit! Thanks!

Comment: same error here, but it didn't work for me.